# VPN Server from my NAS vs VPN server from a dedicated computer on my home network?

Tags: networking, router, vpn, nas

I have read that using your router as your VPN server wasn't a good idea.  Things would slow because your router would be responsible for encrypting and decrypting the data from all your devices.  And even the most powerful routers don't have enough CPU to encrypt and decrypt the data from multiple devices on your network.

I'm guessing that this might also apply to VPN servers on my NAS.  My NAS is responsible for so many other things like backing up computers, streaming movies and musics, etc.

So, wouldn't a VPN server on a dedicated old computer be the best solution?  It's sole responsibility would be to manage the VPN server, encrypting and decrypting VPN traffic.

What do you experts think?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to quantify your needs and resources - particularly the CPU's in the available systems, and what the VPN is required for.

I have several offices which I connect using VPNs on an ASUS AC1900 dual band gigabit router.   I use a similar router with VPN at home, and do heavy backups over it.   (I do note that in both cases I'm only encrypting traffic to key destinations, but that would be the majority of traffic) - as if your needs are not extremely high, using a decent router is the way to go - Consensus is you should be able to get > 40 megabits over VPN from an ASUS RT-AC68 or better.

(The statement that " even the most powerful routers don't have enough CPU to encrypt and decrypt the data from multiple devices on your network." is patently incorrect - there are any number of x86 boxes with multiple interfaces configured as routers, and they are more then up to pushing anything a typical home environment could throw at it - especially if they have AES-NI on the chip - but this is not a requirement) - hell, once upon a time I ran a whole ISP this way.

Using a NAS, it again depends on the NAS, but yes, a lot of them will do an adequate job - but in most cases they use a similar chip to a Router, so doing it on a router is a better idea.

Bottom line - if you get a mid-high end router and put dd-wrt or similar on it, and you don't need to push more then 50 megabit of traffic and can use an OpenVPN router, it should be more then adequate.   If you drop more money on it, you can get even more throughput.

A VPN on a dedicated computer could be a viable solution - but it will consume extra power.  Of-course, throw Linux and an extra couple of NICS on it, and its a router.  Throw in some disks and its a NAS.

Comment: Thanks for the great, informed answer.  Router it is.

One thing you mentioned is that a separate computer dedicated as the VPN server would require extra power.  Would the annual power be all that much?  I would have thought that using an old computer as a VPN server would be the best solution as you would have a dedicated CPU doing the encrypting and decrypting.  It's better than throwing it out, no?

Comment: This is a whole nother question, and depends largely on the age/specs of the computer.  Generally speaking, new computers use a lot less power then old ones. Assuming your computer is drawing on average100 watts, and your power bill is 12.5c/kwh you would be paying 100/1000kwh * $0.125* 8760 hrs per year= $109.50 per year in power to run the PC as a router.

Comment: Generally speaking, the CPUs on routers are a lot less powerful then on Intel based PCs, but they are also a lot more power efficient. This is because they typically use low power ARM based chips - similar to those used in cellphones - where long running time on limited power is way more important then on an always-connected desktop. (Think at least 1/10th the performance @ 1/10th the power)

Comment: Thanks for another good answer.  That's a lot more than I thought to run a computer!  But for me, that might be worth it though if 1. OpenVPN dramatically increases your security and 2. by doing so, it doesn't slow things down appreciably by using OpenVPN on a dedicated computer.  People have paid a lot more for less.

Comment: OpenVPN offers very strong encryption between yourself and a remote point in the Internet, but no security beyond that - the rest is up to the remote network, so it depends on your usage case. How fast is your connection and why/for what do you use a VPN? How many computers are sharing this network ?

Comment: An additional concern would be how to push all your LAN traffic via the VPN PC you probably need to set it up as a router - so 2 nics and lots of fiddling arround.

Comment: Hm...I hate fiddling around.  That usually means it would take forever for me...maybe I'll just stick with OpenVPN via routers for my site-to-site VPN.  (I want to set up two remote networks as one VPN. 
 By doing so, I'm assuming it will increase the speed between the two networks as well as increase safety.)

Comment: Using a VPN will normally not increase the speed between networks - in fact it will marginally decrease it because of the extra work to encrypt and decrypt data) (there are exceptions if your ISP prioritises VPN traffic or if you are sending very compressible traffic across the VPN and have configured it to compress as well - but these are exceptions)

Comment: Hey davidgo, I don't know who's right but someone stated to me while doing research for this that I should possibly see a noticeable increase because he said something to the effect that the shortest route between the two networks would now be pre-determined.  (I guess before, my computer like others might hop around, not necessarily taking the shortest route.

Btw, you seem really nice and helpful.  You think you could help me set some stuff up?

Comment: This may come down to a difference in deployment - I assume that the VPN server is on your equipment as is the VPN client.  If the VPN server is elsewhere on the Internet, and both your computers are acting as clients, then this will probably increase latency.

Comment: That said, the statement "the shortest route between the two networks would now be pre-determined." is incorrect.  The Internet is a packet switched network, and VPN's exist on top of this network and can not instruct the routing table to "pre-determine" a route.

Comment: I pay for a VPN server when I want to be anonymous and go to sites where I don't want to reveal and private information.  I basically also additionally want to use the Site-to-Site VPN using OpenVPN for 1. its extra security between two remote network and 2. the ease of working within one network.  The ease comes from the fact that everything now appears as if they are on one network.  I can for example, hopefully map my NAS onto my remote computer without any difficulty.

Comment: The only difficult is I have to flash DDWRT onto my routers in order to utilize OpenVPN and create OpenSSL certificates for both routers (which is something I have never done before).  It's something I've been pushing off because I know it's going to take forever to get everything to work correctly.  I read a ton of stuff out there on how to do it, but the instructions aren't still very clear to me.  They assume you know things that I don't know.

Comment: Gettting this working on DD-WRT is going to be A LOT easier then doing it on a dedicated PC.

Comment: Would you happen to know the best website that gives the best instructions for novices?  I've tried a few and I'm still confused on some of the steps.

Comment: Nope, and I don't do my sons homework for him either. If you find a howto and get stuck or don't understand something though, a bunch of us are happy to try help.

Comment: I kindly disagree this is like doing someone's homework. I don't need to know how this stuff works. I'm in a different industry (retail). I'd gladly pay someone. I posted this offer for paid help on another site and they took it down. I even went to a computer store and they said they don't do small stuff like that. I've tried A LOT of websites. I'm in the top 1% in IQ (not bragging); I still can't do it b/c sites are crap in explanation. This has been going on for months. You've got to agree it's a total waste of time. Multiply that by millions of people like me.

Comment: I don’t want to appear that I am ungrateful b/c I am! You’re one of the few I’ve encountered these days that counter my view that everyone seems so selfish. Tell me if I’m wrong but I’m guessing you feel that you are being taking advantage of? You are giving all this advice and I’m not giving back. If it makes you feel any better. I help a lot of people in my field of specialty.
I am also truly grateful. I know it takes A LOT of time. I actually have an app idea to remedy unequal sharing (I believe most people don’t share and just hoard info). PM if you’re interested in knowing the details.

Comment: If you like, refer me to a website you have tried and let me know where you got stuck/what didn't work, and I'll try to help.

Comment: I work so the responses take a while when I get some free time.  I'll send you the sites that pop up at the top on google search.  I can tell you that it's extremely frustrating.  I usually start it and try to do it for an hour or two after work.  I give up.  Wait a few weeks and then try again.  The problem is that people who write the explanations write as if they are talking to other people in the IT field.  I'll write up the list and show you where I get stuck when I get out of the office tonight.